# Why isnt my implementation of OnClickListener working?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, onclick, onclicklistener

Nothing inside of my OnClick method is working as far as I can tell and I have no idea why. Im using an emulator to test out the code. The page loads properly and there are two buttons. As seen in the code, I'd log to do an info log saying two different things depending on which button was pressed. I also tried adding android:clickable="true" in the layout. Heres the code:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class UserOnboardActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements OnClickListener {

    private Button selectMaleAvtr;
    private Button selectFemaleAvtr;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_user_onboard);

        selectMaleAvtr = (Button)findViewById(R.id.select_male_avatar_btn);
        selectFemaleAvtr = (Button)findViewById(R.id.select_female_avatar_btn);

        selectMaleAvtr.setOnClickListener(this);
        selectFemaleAvtr.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_user_onboard, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Log.i("whaaat", v.toString());
        Log.i("whaaat", "hello");
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "1", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                .show();
        if(v==selectMaleAvtr) {
            Log.i("UserOnboardActivity", "male avatar button pressed");
        } else if (v==selectFemaleAvtr) {
            Log.i("UserOnboardActivity", "female avatar button pressed");
        }
    }
}
```

XML:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.incubatorcle.dinahealth.UserOnboardActivity">

    <TextView android:text="@string/select_avatar_user_onboard" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/select_avatar_tv"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:soundEffectsEnabled="true"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:id="@+id/select_avatar_btns_lin_lay">
        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Female"
            android:id="@+id/select_female_avatar_btn"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/select_male_avatar_btn"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"/>

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Male"
            android:id="@+id/select_male_avatar_btn"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Next"
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: define: not working .... this should work ... (just small remark: better use `v.getId()==R.id.select_male_avatar_btn` instead `v==selectMaleAvtr`)

Comment: What if the code you are running is not this one.. try clean the project.. and test again...

Comment: @FragmentsNActivities how do I see the stack trace, I thought those only show up after an error?

Comment: @Selvin No Toast shows up and no logs are found in the logcat when either of the buttons are pushed.

Comment: can you paste in your xml?

Comment: @FragmentsNActivities just added it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was I was using a different activity to open the view so the code in this activity was never getting loaded. I solved it by using an intent and then startActivity to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the issue is you have to look for the viewids instead of the view itself:

You can either do:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
        Log.i("whaaat", v.toString());
        Log.i("whaaat", "hello");
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "1", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                .show();
        if(v.getId()==R.id.selectMaleAvtr) {
            Log.i("UserOnboardActivity", "male avatar button pressed");
        } else if (v.getId()==R.id.selectFemaleAvtr) {
            Log.i("UserOnboardActivity", "female avatar button pressed");
        }
    }
```

OR

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {

    case R.id.selectMaleAvtr:
        // Things you want do
        break;

    case R.id.selectFemaleAvtr:
        // Things you want to do
        break;

    default:
        break;
    }

}
```

Comment: That is correct. Might be a glitch. Can you try clearing out the logs and trying again?